# WCF JSON service using Java Jersey client - Error: OperationFormatter encountered an invalid Message body

Tags: json, wcf, rest, jersey

I am trying to invoke a WCF method from my java client (using jersey) but I am getting the below error in the service log whenever I try to invoke the service.

OperationFormatter encountered an invalid Message body. Expected to find an attribute with name 'type' and value 'object'. Found value 'string'.

I am not sure if I am passing the values to the service in correct format..

The service accepts 2 parameters (object object1, boolean commit), I am passing the value in json format as below,

Service :

```
[OperationContract]
        [FaultContract(typeof(SLFault))]
        [WebInvoke]
        public string InsertObject(object object1, bool commit)
```

json input:

```
{commit=[true], object1=[{"infoObjectParams":{"DynamicFields":{"idx_Indicator":["Yes"]},"Name":"Test",additionalProperties":{}}}]}
```

But I am always getting the above error, can someone please helpe me fix my issue?

Thanks,
BB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was passing wrong format to the WCF service.

Once I modified the input format as below, everything worked...

{"commit":true,"object1":{"DynamicFields":{"idx_Indicator":["Yes"]},"additionalProperties":{}}}

Thanks,
BB